Unused i18n keys and duplicate keys in hugo
I'm managing a Hugo framework repository containing roughly 5000 i18n keys. I suspect that around 40% of these keys are either unused or duplicated. Are there any package or tools that can automate the process of identifying and removing these unused keys.
FYI: I have used i18n keys in content (hugo_repo/content/*), layout (hugo_repo/layouts/*) and data file (hugo_repo/data/*).
I tried to extract the keys utilised in layout files with js, employing regex to isolate key IDs from {{ T "keyID" }}. This method successfully captures all the used keys, enabling comparison with the i18n file to identify and remove unused keys. However, I'm encountering difficulty in determining the keys used within content files (hugo_repo/content/*) and data files (hugo_repo/data/*). Any suggestions on how to address this challenge? any package already available for maintaining hugo i18n?

There is no method to easily do that, as there is no hook in Gohugo linked to the translation, that one could use to make a list of all translations used.
Here is how I would do it.
Assuming you have this i18n file:
[key1]
other = "translation"

[key2]
other = "lorem ipsum"

...

Swap it by another one where you replace each translation text by %%i18n_[the corresponding key]%%. It does not need to be exactly that syntax. Just make it singular enough to spot it using regexp on the last step.
[key1]
other = "%%i18n_key1%%"

[key2]
other = "%%i18n_key2%%"

...

That can be easily autogenerated by extracting all keys between brackets in your original i18n file, then a small loop to create the new file.
Once you have swapped, render the site. Then iterate through all the HTML files and use a regexp to search for strings that match the pattern %%i18n_[characters]%%.
All the matches are i18n keys used. All the ones that do not match are not used in your site.
